# React Quill character limit for pasted text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I've made a limit for entered characted in `react-quill` in the following way

```
  const handleChange = (text) => {
    const value = text.substring(0, maxLength);
    onChange(value);
  };
```

```
<ReactQuill
  value={value}
  onChange={(text) => handleChange(text)}
 />
```

The problem is that if I delete any characters (by pressing backspace) after I pasted the text, the editor adds some weird symbols (looks like a part of HTML entity) at the end of the pasted text.

Here is an example:

I paste a long string, it gets cut off where it's supposed to. The string is

```
<p>A game known as "football" was played
```

This is what it turns into after I delete a letter (it doesn't necessarily have to be the last letter in the string)

```
<p>A game known as "football" was playe<
```

Then I delete two more and get

```
<p>A game known as "football" was pla&am
```

So, instead of being removed the characters turn into HTML tags/entities.

I also tried to modife `handleChange` function so that it removes HTML tags and entities.

```
  const handleChange = (text, source) => {
    if (source === 'api') {
      return;
    }

    const value = text.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '').substring(0, maxLength);

    onChange(value);
  };
```

But then it doesn't let me enter spaces even if the limit is not exceeded.

My question is how do I avoid that and if there is a better way to introduce a character limit in `react-quill` ?

Comment: Hello, did you resolve?